# How to parse XML with tag names that contain non-latin Unicode characters with the DocumentBuilder DOM parser on Android

Tags: android, xml, dom, unicode

Ok, I have an Android app that was written by someone else but it's my job to maintain and further develop. The app consumes an API that answers in XML format. The code is pretty standard:

```
InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(in);
```

Everything is OK until there are non-latin characters in the tag names. 
For example this is OK:

```
<Milen>some_text</Milen>
```

But this raises an exception:

```
<Милен>some_text</Милен>
```

The exception is [INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/org/w3c/dom/DOMException.java#DOMException.0INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR). Upon some investigation I found out that the implementation of the [DOM API](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) is [org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robovm/robovm-rt/0.0.2/org/apache/harmony/xml/dom/DocumentImpl.java#DocumentImpl.isXMLIdentifier%28java.lang.String%29). And the exception is raised [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robovm/robovm-rt/0.0.2/org/apache/harmony/xml/dom/NodeImpl.java#NodeImpl.setName%28org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.NodeImpl%2Cjava.lang.String%29) on line 286. The if check boils down to this method:

```
private static boolean isXMLIdentifierPart(char c) {
    return isXMLIdentifierStart(c) || (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c == '-') || (c == '.');
}
```

This essentially rules out any non-latin characters. Howerver, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#International_use) any Unicode character is a valid tag name.

So my questions are:

1. Why is there such a check that runs against the standard?
2. **What are my options for getting the DOM parser to work with non-latin Unicode characters?**

Some additional notes:

- The server returns correct UTF-8 response
- I've tried using [XML escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) but obviously this is converted back to the original Unicode before the check in `isXMLIdentifierPart`
- I strongly prefer to stick to the DOM parser API since the processing afterwards assumes a [Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) object is passed to it. Rewriting the processing would be A LOT of work.

Two solutions that I'm thinking of are:

1. Taking the code of the org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl implementation and creating a custom parser that lacks the problematic check.
2. Having the server encode the non-latin characters with some custom schema that uses latin-only characters (\u1234 or U+1234 won't work) and then decoding it back after the parser has done it's work.

However both solutions are non-standard and and don't like them both. So any proper ways of doing this are more than welcome!!!

Disclaimer: I'm new to the Android platform and there's a possibility that I'm missing something simple/obvious. However, after two days of research and experimenting I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> according to this any Unicode character is a valid tag name.

Not quite *any* character, but yes, in Fifth Edition the vast majority of non-ASCII characters are allowed (before that the rules were rather complicated, but still a lot was allowed).

> Why is there such a check that runs against the standard?

Because the Harmony DOM implementation is a buggy, non-conformant, poorly-maintained heap that couldn't be bothered to implement the old spec properly so just blanket-disallowed non-ASCII. Amongst its many other problems.

This is [issue 78387](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78387) FWIW.

> What are my options for getting the DOM parser to work with non-latin Unicode characters?

See if you can find an alternative, less broken DOM implementation.

> Taking the code of the org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl implementation and creating a custom parser that lacks the problematic check.

(And yes this would probably have to be a proper fork as it would be quite hard to do with subclassing alone. Too many of the classes have explicit references to each other.)

Comment: Thanks! The link to the Google Code issue was very helpful as it lead me to Xerces-For-Android which proved to be a very good parsing library.
I know that solutions in links are not much appreciated here because links and their associated resources may disappear in the future. So, please edit your post to include the link to the library.